# Decorative elements for webpages

Tags: html, css

Do you know some source where is it possible to download some decorative elements (images) for web pages? (e.g. little images that can be used as list-style-image etc.)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best one is

http://www.iconfinder.com

Answer (score 1):

There are many:

1. www.ender-design.com/rg/dots.html
2. www.websitebullets.com/
3. www.hitguru.net/small-web-page-bullets.php

or you can [search google](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=Gdb1TY3XItGyrAf-9-XOBg&ved=0CBsQvwUoAQ&q=bullets%20for%20web%20pages&spell=1&biw=1024&bih=667)

Comment: Damn! Back to 90s! :)
This one's also nice: http://www.stylegala.com/features/bulletmadness/

Answer (score 0):

You can google for the images and lot of images are available on internet
Sometimes you will get a image containing all symbols required. In this case we can use image editing tools to extract required images :)